# add Polyline with Ti.map Appcelerator

Tags: android, ios, maps, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm developing a mobile iOS / Android app with Appcelerator Studio and I'm using Ti.map module . I want to get physical routing between two geographic points (origin and destination) and i 'm using Google Directions API for to obtain the full informations for the route .

But the method addPolyline seems not work and does not appear on the map the route from origin to destination.

This is the code:

```
var mySpecialRoute = MapModule.createPolyline({
            name: 'personal route',
            points: myPolyline,
            color: 'red',
            width : numPolyline
        });

mapview.addPolyline(mySpecialRoute);
```

and this is my polylines array:

```
(
  "ydhoGuot}@c@bAiBvE",
  "gihoGyft}@qCoBGEIGmA{@o@g@yBkBYSYQqCi@a@G}BS_@CkAEKAgAMWCwBcA",
  "ykioGuwt}@w@a@a@W_@UYI]KSCcDOaCOq@C{AK{@Gy@MsAIq@Gg@IWAE@",
  "uijoGa~t}@aAMOAeAMUCOAE?C?A?C?A@EB",
  "ytpoGkvu}@OAC?EAGCMEWGUEIAA?C@A@C@KR"
```

)

Where I wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Mirco

Answer (score 0):

The polyline property wants an array of points. See the [4.1.0 Sample App](https://github.com/appcelerator-developer-relations/appc-sample-ti410/blob/master/app/controllers/index.js#L37-L55) as example.

Comment: Thanks! It was also very useful this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm